# Best way to create a derived class when you only need to modify a method of one of the parent's dependencies

Tags: c++, oop, object, inheritance, singleton

I will try to be as clear as possible but it may be difficult.

In my code I include some external class `A`, however, a method of this class (lets call it `A::method`) does not work as I would want so I would have to instead use a modified version of `A` (`DerA`) where I have only modified said method via inheritance.

However this method is very complex, it calls other methods of classes that are included in `A` that I don't use at all. After digging enough I find that `A::method` calls some method `B::other_method` where `B` is in fact a singleton (not included in `A` but on a deeper level). I could easily create a derived singleton `DerB` so that if `DerA` called this class method instead of `B` everything would work as I want. I have no idea how to do this, maybe its not even possible.

The alternative would be to create this `DerA` class and define a new `DerA::method` but in doing so I would have to copy paste almost all of the source code of `A` and its dependances which is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: sorry but your problem is to 'copy paste ' some code or the B singleton?

Comment: the problem is that I don't want to have to copy hundreds of lines of code only to change some class `B` that is used internally in the function I want to modify. `B` is a singleton so maybe doing this is easier because of this or maybe its irrelevant.

Comment: Is `A::method` virtual?  If it is not virtual, can you make it virtual?  It sounds like you don't need to make `class DerA`, rather you need to copy `A` to a new class `C` and then modify it as needed (mostly by eliminating all the things you don't need).

Comment: the B element is hardCoded? or given by an external function? sometimes to avoid this problem library create other function that just returns that object

Comment: Its not virtual. I don't think I understand you. In this case `A` is a parser class and `method` is the main "parse" method. This parser can parse different types of objects. I only want the "read" method to work differently on a single case which in my case means I would need to modify a method of one of this objects which I called `B`.

Comment: Yes, the `B` is hardcoded, I cannot modify this from lets say modifying the arguments of `A::method`.

Comment: Implement an adapter or decorator.